# не могу сохранить в базу данных mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

это моя модель с схемой самой бд

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

import 'mongodb';

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users');
mongoose.connection;



var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

function createUser(newUser, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            return newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports = createUser;
```

а это при post запросе я пытаюсь сохранить все данные в бд

```
var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log(user);


    });
```

А вот что выдает консоль

```
{ name: 'name',
  user_name: 'Aleksey Bilous',
  user_email: 'alekseybilous@gmail.com',
  user_pass: '1',
  user_passConf: '1' }
/home/leha/Desktop/Projects/test/models/user.js:44
            return newUser.save(callback);
                       ^

TypeError: newUser.save is not a function
```

сами данные приходят все хорошо, но почему то не хочет восприимать метод save, есть идеи ??

Comment: Чисто по js он все верно ругается - User не имеет реализации метода save и он не понимает откуда его брать.  Мб тут ответ найдешь https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.save/ . Судя по написанному, то save надо применять к коллекции, передав методу в качестве параметра новую запись newUser